# SQL query returns one row too few

Tags: php, sql

SOLUTION: Make sure you don't 'use up' any `$responses->fetch_assoc()`s before the while loop.
I performed `mysqli_fetch_array($responses);`.

In php I have this sql query (simplified for your convenience, but the problem remains)

```
$sql = "SELECT id, content FROM responses ORDER BY RAND()";
$responses = $conn->query($sql);
```

where the responses table looks like this:

```
+----+----------+--------+------+
| id | content  | userId | part |
+----+----------+--------+------+
|  4 | peewee   |     31 |    1 |
|  5 | tallinn  |     31 |    1 |
|  6 | dewey    |     31 |    1 |
|  7 | stanford |     31 |    1 |
+----+----------+--------+------+
```

That doesn't format properly so all you need to know is that the id and content rows are different for each entry while the rest is the same for each.

The problem is, when I do a while loop on $responses like so:

```
while ($row = $responses->fetch_assoc()) {
    $responseId = $row["id"];
    $content = $row["content"];
    echo " id: ".$responseId;
    echo " content: ".$content;
}
```

I always get 1 record fewer than there are. In this case, since there are 4 rows, I would only see 3 echoed. However, it is not always the same 3, nor are they in the same order. If I remove the ORDER BY RAND() clause, then it is always the first record which is left out.

Thanks in advance

Cheers

Comment: Can you show the whole segment of code from the query to the while loop.

Comment: `ORDER BY` (without `LIMIT`) _cannot_ alter the size of the result set, so something else is going on here.

Comment: You probably perform another `$responses->fetch_assoc()` before you start the loop.

Comment: Thanks KIKO! I did $responseArray = mysqli_fetch_array($responses); to test something and forgot to get rid of it.

Comment: Ah, that happens to all of us. Many, many, way to many times. 

Comment: Well, I'll take note of that. Next time I'll be more thorough before posting.